# Multipeer Connectivity just stopped finding peers all of the sudden

Tags: ios, game-center, multipeer-connectivity

I used this piece of code to initialize an advertiser and a browser:

```
    peerid = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[shared.identity objectAtIndex:0]];

    session2 = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerid];
    session2.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"18", @"Male"] forKeys:@[@"age", @"gender"]];

    advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:peerid discoveryInfo:dict serviceType:@"service"];

    advertiser.delegate = self;
    [advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];

    browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:peerid serviceType:@"service"];

    browser.delegate = self;
    [browser startBrowsingForPeers];
```

and it has always worked flawlessly.
But, when I either updated to iOS 7.1.1 or added Game Center, thus provisioned the app, it just won't find other peers. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean "worked flawlessly"?  Did you have two iOS devices finding and connecting to each other?  Are you sure both devices are on the same network (for eg: I've had both devices working and then one decides to flip to another WiFi network)

Comment: By "worked flawlessly" I mean that the devices were able to find each other and connect. And yes, the devices are on the same network and it doesn't work even with Bluetooth on. Is there a special way I have to provision the app with? Because, it was working fine until I created a provision profile for Game Center.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!! Both devices had the same peerid and, since I had additional code which prevented from displaying two peers with the same id, it didn't work.